# How to return specific days between two dates in PHP

Tags: php, date

I encountered a problem today that perhaps others may need help with, so I'm posting the answer here.

The client wanted me to save the dates of every Monday and Wednesday between 2 given dates.

(Neither the start nor end date actually started on a Monday or Wednesday either).

Answer is below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use `DateTime` and `DateInterval` to skip directly to same day of the next week and keep track of whether it exceeds the end date or not using `diff()` method.

**CODE:**

```
$next_monday    = new DateTime("next Monday");
$next_wednesday = new DateTime("next Wednesday");
$one_week = new DateInterval("P1W");
$end_date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d")." +100 days");


$valid_dates = [];

while(true){
    if($next_monday->diff($end_date)->invert === 1){
        break;
    }
    $valid_dates[] = $next_monday->format("Y-m-d");
    if($next_wednesday->diff($end_date)->invert === 1){
        break;
    }
    $valid_dates[] = $next_wednesday->format("Y-m-d");
    $next_monday->add($one_week);
    $next_wednesday->add($one_week);
}


foreach($valid_dates as $each_date){
    echo $each_date," ",date("D",strtotime($each_date)),"<br/>"; // to cross verify whether it's really Monday or Wednesday or not. 
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2018-10-01 Mon
2018-10-03 Wed
2018-10-08 Mon
2018-10-10 Wed
2018-10-15 Mon
2018-10-17 Wed
2018-10-22 Mon
2018-10-24 Wed
2018-10-29 Mon
2018-10-31 Wed
2018-11-05 Mon
2018-11-07 Wed
2018-11-12 Mon
2018-11-14 Wed
2018-11-19 Mon
2018-11-21 Wed
2018-11-26 Mon
2018-11-28 Wed
2018-12-03 Mon
2018-12-05 Wed
2018-12-10 Mon
2018-12-12 Wed
2018-12-17 Mon
2018-12-19 Wed
2018-12-24 Mon
2018-12-26 Wed
2018-12-31 Mon
2019-01-02 Wed
```

**NOTE:**

You may add `86400` seconds to start date's `strtotime()` and run a loop to check for each consecutive day(which will work fine). However, if you try to add `86400 * 2` or `86400 * 5` to skip past 2 or 5 days from current day, you will face issues if you don't start your loop from start date's `midnight`.

Comment: Or if your start date isn't today, line 1 would become (where X is the start date):
$next_monday    = new DateTime('XXXX-XX-XX');          
$next_monday    ->modify('next monday');

Answer (score 2):

**Instructions**

First save all the required days of the week in an array. I am using short date form (D) but you could use the long form (l):

```
$days = ["Mon", "Wed"];   //If <PHP7 use $days = array("Mon", "Wed");
```

Next, convert your start and end date in to timestamps:

```
$starttimestamp = strtotime($start_date);
$endtimestamp = strtotime($end_date);
```

Next, perform a FOR loop, adding 86400 microseconds (exactly 1 day) to every cycle. This will give us a new timestamp for every day between the two days. Create a new day string for each loop:

```
for(  $j=$starttimestamp;  $j<=$endtimestamp;  $j+=86400)
{
    $tmpday = date('D',$j);
    ...
}
```

Finally, perform an in_array check ( eg. if needle in haystack ) to see whether the DAY matches any of our required days:

```
for(  $j=$starttimestamp;  $j<=$endtimestamp;  $j+=86400)
{
    $tmpday = date('D',$j);

    if(in_array($tmpday, $avail_days) ){
           echo date('Y-m-d',$j);
    }
}
```

That's all there is to it. The entire code can be seen below. I hope this helps someone else in the future:

**Entire Code**

```
$avail_days     = ["Mon", "Wed"];    //If <PHP7 use $days = array("Mon", "Wed"); 
$starttimestamp = strtotime($your_start_date);
$endtimestamp   = strtotime($your_end_date);

for( $j = $starttimestamp;  $j <= $endtimestamp;  $j += 86400 )
{

    $tmpday = date('D',$j);

    if(in_array($tmpday, $avail_days) ){

           echo date('Y-m-d',$j);  //This date has a day that matches your required days!

    }

}
```

Comment: Feel free to improve on this if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: How about only iterating over Mondays' and Wednesdays' only ? Find the first `Monday` and precompute the gap between Mon-Wed and Wed-Mon. Now iterate using a while loop and use a boolean flag to switch the days to increment the previous timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Do you have some sample code for that?
I'd also be interested to know if we could extend it to more complicated patterns, such as every Nth Monday, only the first and last Friday etc

Comment: Good answer James and well-written. *But*, what about those on servers that do not support `[]` (array) syntax? The question/answer should reflect on the use of the PHP version which is very important and for those who don't know about it and how to use it. The `[]` notation isn't supported for versions below PHP 5.4 as per the manual on arrays http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @james I noticed. However, that comment was meant for me. It's always best to ping someone directly since they may no longer be present in the question ;-) bit of a pro Stack tip.

Comment: @james I have added my answer to illustrate my idea. For situations such as every Nth Monday, it becomes a bit tricky, but it's achievable. I have left it up till here for the scope of this problem.

Comment: I downvoted your answer, because its not DST-save. In regions with daylight saving time not all days are 24*60*60 seconds long. Therefore looping through days by adding 24*60*60 can introduce nasty bugs. You should use DateTime instead. DateTime nows about timezone-changes introduced by DST.

Comment: @simon.ro thanks for letting me know. Would it work if I just replace my references of "date" to "DateTime"? Or do I need to do something with strtotime too?

Comment: @james neither. The problem is your loop: It assumes every day is 86400 seconds longs. The answer of @vivek_23 doesn't because it uses `DateTime::add()` which does respect timezones and DST