# the selected days between 2 dates as a weekly cycle in php

Tags: php, loops

```
$startdate = strtotime($_POST[startdate]);

$enddate = strtotime($_POST[enddate]);

if (!empty($_POST[startdate]))

{

$fmonday = strtotime("last monday", strtotime($_POST[startdate])); 

$txtDays = $_POST[txtDay]; 
//from checked boxes checked dates  values "+ 1 day", "+2 day", ...

foreach($txtDays as $txtDay)
{
$txtGetDate =  strtotime($txtDay, $fmonday);
if ($txtGetDate  >=  $startdate)
{
echo date("d-m-Y", $txtGetDate)."<br>";
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime("+1 week", $txtGetDate))."dddd<br>";
}
}
}
//-------------------------
```

I have problem with weekly cycle. I need listed of selected dates in a range but weekly cycle.
For example;

I selected Mon And Fri in a week; but its variable; sometimes just 1 day sometimes 5 days. This dates in a range between stardate and enddate.
I need listed of date look like as below

01.01.2020 Mon
05.01.2020 Fri
08.01.2020 Mon
12.01.2020 Fri
15.01.2020 Mon
19.01.2020 Fri

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
<tr><td style="width:15%;">Dönem Başlangıç</td>
<td style="width:15%;">
<input type="text" name="startdate" style="width:95%;height:20px;text-align:center;"></td>
<td style="width:15%;">Dönem Bitiş</td>
<td style="width:15%;">
<input type="text" name="enddate" style="width:95%;height:20px;text-align:center;"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="deneme" name="txtSali[]" value="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'monday this week' ))?>"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="deneme" name="txtSali[]" value="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'tuesday this week' ))?>"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="deneme" name="txtSali[]" value="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'wednesday this week' ))?>"></td>
<td><input type="cheackbox" class="deneme" name="txtSali[]" value="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'thursday this week' ))?>"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="deneme" name="txtSali[]" value="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'friday this week' ))?>"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="deneme" name="txtSali[]" value="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'saturday this week' ))?>"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="deneme" name="txtSali[]" value="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'sunday this week' ))?>"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your user can pick dates between a start date and end date, and you want a list of those dates plus all dates that result from repeating those dates in the weeks to come until the end date is reached?

Assuming the user input has appropriate format:

```php
$result = [];

$startDate = new DateTime($_POST['startdate']);
$endDate = new DateTime($_POST['enddate']);

// create an array of this kind with all user-selected dates
// maybe add a check for being greater than the start date
$selectedDates = [new DateTime($_POST['firstSelectedDate']), new DateTime($_POST['secondSelectedDate']];

foreach ($selectedDates as $selectedDate) {
    $interval = new DateInterval('P7D');
    $range = new DatePeriod($selectedDate, $interval, $endDate);

    foreach ($range as $date) {
        $result[] = $date;
    }
}

sort($result);
foreach ($result as $date) {
    echo $date->format('d.m.Y D'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Hi ziegler, but i have problem with checked date i thing cause of result not look like as below <br> 01.01.2020 Mon
05.01.2020 Fri
08.01.2020 Mon
12.01.2020 Fri
15.01.2020 Mon
19.01.2020 Fri <br> look like as below <br> Mon<br>Mon<br>Mon<br>Mon<br>Fri<br>Fri<br>Fri<br>Fri   Please help me. Thank you for your understanding. Best Regards Murat ÖZKAN

Comment: @Muratözkan Where is your problem exactly? I am afraid I cannot understand you. Is it a problem with the HTML formatting, or are the dates themselves not correct?

Comment: Dear sir  im so sorry now i update my script with my HTML code :) thank you for your help. Please help me. Thank you for all. Best Regards Murat Özkan

Comment: I still do not understand where the problem is. According to your first comment, the number of desired dates and the day of the week seem to be correct, except the ordering and the missing dates. I have updated my solution to add the ordering, but I do not know why the dates are missing.

Comment: im so sorry sir date is ok. like this 30.08.2021 Mon
06.09.2021 Mon
13.09.2021 Mon
20.09.2021 Mon
31.08.2021 Tue
07.09.2021 Tue
but i need like this 30.08.2021 Mon
31.08.2021 Tue
06.09.2021 Mon
07.09.2021 Tue
13.09.2021 Mon
14.09.2021 Tue

Comment: Thank you for all im not new but this subject is so difficult for me i dont understand. :) best regards MURAT ÖZKAN

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537591/how-to-return-specific-days-between-two-dates-in-php/52537592

Comment: Can you tell me what your input values for the following variables in my solution are? $startDate, $endDate and $selectedDates?
If you plug in $_POST['startdate'] = '2021-08-30', $_POST['enddate'] = '2021-09-15' and as selectedDates the dates '2021-08-30' and '2021-08-31' you will get your desired list in your comment above...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537591/how-to-return-specific-days-between-two-dates-in-php/52537592 -------i find answer with this link thank you for all Best Regards Murat Özkan